# jquery removeClass() not removing all classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element like this:

```
<div class="one two three" id="waterhorse">horse</div>
```

When I run this code in the browser console:

```
$("#waterhorse").removeClass();
```

I get this:

```
[<div id=​"waterhorse" class=​"one two three">​horse​</div>​]
```

In other words, it doesn't work; it doesn't remove any classes on the element. I unfortunately can't reproduce it in jsfiddle.

However, I can remove a specific class:

```
$("#waterhorse").removeClass("two");
```

Also, this will remove all classes:

```
$("#waterhorse").removeAttr("class");
```

Any idea why the latter works to remove all classes, but the former doesn't?

Comment: This is not reproducible in jsfiddle?

Comment: @roasted Citing from the [jQuery spec](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/): "If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed." So this should work.

Comment: @Sirko  Ya, just saw that in doc

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/tKTgE/1/

Comment: @mises Any particular browser (version) you see this behavior? Or any special context?

Comment: [It must work though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1424991/1225328).

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: Closing as too localised. The code does work, your problem cannot be replicated, and you can't even be bothered to elaborate the details.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, Canary, and FF, all with the same result.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I know the code used to work with an older version of jQuery.  It seems like it's a problem with the combination of jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.0.  If I remove the reference to jQuery UI, then the removeClass() function works again.  I will try to test the slightly newer versions of jQuery and JQuery UI to see if they fix the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Seems like this is a known problem with jQuery and jQueryUI not playing nicely together:

[Odd issue with jQuery .removeClass() not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532327/odd-issue-with-jquery-removeclass-not-doing-anything)

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9015

The answer above is a workaround that uses `.removeAttr('class')` instead of `.removeClass()`

Comment: I had the same problem. It “exists” even if it shouldn’t. Workaround works nicely.

Answer (score -1):

If we read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) it states this:

> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will
>   be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are
>   specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

In other words, `.removeClass()` should work without parameters. I've tried this in FF and this works as intended.

I tried to reproduce the problem you are experiencing, but it couldn't do it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRzf2/)

```
<div class="one two three" id="waterhorse">horse</div>

$("#waterhorse").removeClass();
$("#waterhorse").addClass("four");
console.log($("#waterhorse"));
```

What browser version are you using?

Comment: Using latest chrome, canary, FF. I also cannot reproduce in jsfiddle. Strange problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in $(document).ready() to achieve this.

```
$("#waterhorse").attr("class", "");

or

$("#waterhorse").removeClass();
```

Hope this will help you.:)